# Why the "as" operator must be passed a reference or nullable type?

Tags: c#, type-conversion

So I know the `as` operator in C# must be passed a reference or nullable type, because it can return null, what I don't understand is - why?

Returning null should be separate from what arguments are being passed to it, since I don't know its inner workings I can only draw on my knowledge of ordinary methods, which would be that what I return, normally, would have nothing to do with what arguments I pass.

In other words, I imagine the `as` operator to be something like this pseudocode:

```
private object as(object arg1, object arg2)
{
    if (arg1 can be cast to arg2)
        return (arg2)arg1;
    else
        return null;
}
```

Why would it matter if the passed argument is a reference or a value type, then?

Comment: Your "pseudocode version" of `as` doesn't actually do what the `as` operator does, so it's not actually a valid example. Your `as` operator returns `object`, but the _actual_ `as` operator returns whatever type is specified for the expression. If that type is a value type, which of course cannot have a `null` value, how would that even work? Anyway, your question has already been asked and answered...see marked duplicate.

Comment: @PeterDuniho, oh so what it actually would look like is `private T as(object arg1, T arg2)` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Imagine you want to cast some object to `int` with help of `as`

```
int number = object as int;
```

If object is `int` the cast is successful and result is stored into `int number`. If the object is not `int` then conversion returns `null` and it can**not** be stored in variable of non-nullable type. That's why compiler doesn't allow to use `as` with non-nullable types.

Comment: but `object o = object as int` fails because int is not a reference type, I am asking why that happens.

Comment: The expression `object as int` makes no sense; `object` is a type, not a variable. But assume you had `object intObject =3;`. At that point, the variable intObject refers to a *boxed integer* that represents the integer 3. So `int i = (int)intObject:` would result in the variable `i` containing the value 3. But, if you tried to do the cast using `as` with `intObject as int`, it looks like a cast, but, it results in an expression of type `int`. The `as` keyword's failure behavior is to return `null` when the conversion is not possible. But, `null` isn't a valid value for Value Types like `int`.

Comment: @J.Doe `object o = x as int` is first casting x to `int` and then casting it to `object`.    Basically the `x as int` part doesn't know that you want to take it's result and do another cast.  And really in that case why wouldn't you just do `object o = x as object`?  Why try to cast to `int` when you ultimately want to cast to `object`.

Comment: @juharr, oh so what the method signature actually would look like is sort of `private T as(object arg1, T arg2)` ?

Comment: @J.Doe More like `public TOut as<TIn, TOut>(TIn arg) where TOut : class`